# Median value for one year and median value for another year, where dates are in the same column

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a price column and a date column. The date column includes 2019 and 2018.

I'm trying to get the median price value for each year.

Tried Median with If as an array specifically using the date and less than or greater than to identify if the proper year is selected.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the array formula - it will be a little simpler

```
{=MEDIAN(IF(E1=YEAR($B$2:$B$5);$A$2:$A$5;""))}
```

[image]

Array formula after editing is confirmed by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

**Addition:**

No, `AND` function can't work with arrays. In case with additional conditions use following array formula:

```
{=MEDIAN(IF(E1=YEAR($B$2:$B$5)*($C$2:$C$5="x");$A$2:$A$5;""))}
```

[image]

And empty cells are not included in the `MEDIAN` calculation because previous conditions.

Comment: Worth to mention that the formula you provide is using a localized delimiter `;` which is not the US english default (which is `,`) that is usually used on this website.

Comment: One more item to add. There are some rows that are blank and also some rows that shouldn't be counted. If there is an additional cell that indicates the letter x then that should be processed. Let's say in your column C there's only three out of four that are selected with this indicator. Would the best function to use be the AND?

Comment: Amazing! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Median() function with a nested IF.

```
=MEDIAN(IF(YEAR($B$2:$B$6)=D$1,$A$2:$A$6))
```

If you already have a version of Excel that supports Dynamic Arrays, you can just enter the formula. If you have a version without Dynamic Arrays, you need to use Ctrl+Shift+Enter to confirm the formula.

[image]